# How to access PageRemote attribute in class library

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

I use .NET 6 and I want to use `[PageRemote]` in class libarary, I installed `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc` in my class library, but still I can't use `[PageRemote]` in my class library.
How can I use `[PageRemote]` In class libraries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding the ASP.NET Core framework reference into your class library as is shown here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/target-aspnetcore?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#use-the-aspnet-core-shared-framework

> To reference ASP.NET Core, add the following `<FrameworkReference>` element to your project file:
>
> ```
> <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
>
>    <PropertyGroup>
>        <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
>    </PropertyGroup>
>
>    <ItemGroup>
>        <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
>    </ItemGroup>
>
> </Project>
> ```